# Determining the center of the viewed space in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

I am displaying a CATiledLayer via a scrollview which displays a map. When the user presses a button, I want to determine the bounds of the catiledlayer that the user is currently viewing and place an image there.

In other words, I need to determine the portion of the CATiledLayer that is being displayed, then determine the center point of that portion.

Appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: What about the bounds of the layer?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `scrollView.contentOffset` (which returns a `CGPoint`) which will give you where all the content in your scroll view is in relation to the origin point of the scroll view. So if your `CATiledLayer` is up and to the left you'd get some thing like (-50, -100). Take those values, multiply by -1 and then add them to `scrollView.center` property (also returns a `CGPoint`). This will give you a `CGPoint` coordinate that if used as the center point of a new-subview within scrollView will center that view within the current frame.

```
CGPoint currentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x * -1, scrollView.contentOffset.y * -1);
CGPoint center = CGRectMake(scrollView.center.x + currentOffset.x, scrollView.center.y + currentOffset.y);
```

I haven't tested this code, but it *should* work or at least give you a general starting point!

Comment: Nope, this is putting the point on the far portion of the view or completely off the view to the left. I will play with it a bit, but part of the trouble is accounting for the zoomScale